# Temporarily 'suspending' a Symfony app

Tags: symfony1

I need to perform an upgrade/enhancement on a Symfony (1.3.8) powered website. the site will be offline for a few days atleast. Does anyone know how I can setup an "temporaily offline" page, using the Symfony framework?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Following is a quote from [A Gentle Introduction to symfony, chapter 16](http://www.symfony-project.org/gentle-introduction/1_4/en/16-Application-Management-Tools#chapter_16_sub_managing_a_production_application):

You can temporarily disable your application - for instance, when you need to upgrade a library or a large amount of data.

```
php symfony project:disable APPLICATION_NAME ENVIRONMENT_NAME
```

By default, a disabled application displays the `sfConfig::get('sf_symfony_lib_dir')/exception/data/unavailable.php` page, but if you create your own unavailable.php file in your project's config/ directory, symfony will use it instead.

The project:enable task reenables the application and clears the cache.

```
php symfony project:enable APPLICATION_NAME ENVIRONMENT_NAME
```

**project:disable currently has no effect if the check_lock parameter is not set to true in settings.yml.**

Comment: The last line in this is very important and easy to miss. You need to enable check_lock.

Comment: Indeed, I made it bold to add emphasis.

Comment: @Maerlyn Is it possible to disable app manually?without commands?

Comment: @denys281 check out what the task does and do it manually: http://trac.symfony-project.org/browser/branches/1.4/lib/task/project/sfProjectDisableTask.class.php

Comment: Thanks.Just upload to the hosting  frontend_prod.lck file :-)